# Can't Uninstall HP ProtectTools

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I have HP ProBook with preinstalled HP Protect Tools
I tried to uninstall it, but it say that **HP FILE SANITIZER** &
**HP Device Access Manager** must be first uninstalled. But i can't find them in Install/Uninstall tab.
My USB flash drive is unaccessible and my newly created partition, but also i
 accept answer how to uninstall corrupt HP Device Access Manager(It not appear even
 in searchbar in Win 10 or Install/Uninstall programs).
*Sorry For My Bad English*
Don't answer uninstall HP Device Access Manager. I can't to.

Answer (score 0):

For HP File santizer what I did was found the exe and reran it, it gave me an option to uninstall.

Here is the path for my file, try searching your system for "sp68055"
C:\SWSetup\sp68055\setup.exe

Another thing to do is download the latest version which should give you uninstall option:
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_144696_1&swEnvOid=4158

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes **HP Device Access Manager** is called **Device Access Manager for HP Protecttools**. Try searching for HP and then you will be able to find the relevant program in whatever the way it is called in your system.